# Is there a way to use Sverchok's ScriptNode without defining in_sockets?

Tags: python, scripting, sverchok

Is there a way to use Sverchok's ScriptNode without defining in_sockets? So, writing a script using constants and creating out_sockets solely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and this is by design.

"ScriptNode" is the oldest of the available script nodes, the most recent iteration of the scriptnode is *ScriptNode Lite* (SNLite). Let me suggest using that instead because it exposes quite a bit more back-end functionality.

Find SNLite's development thread / docs / examples: [here](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/942)

One way around this, is a dummy socket.

```
"""
in dummy v
out verts v
"""

verts.append([])
verts[0].extend([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [2,0,0]])
```

If you really don't want to see the socket, then you might do

```
"""
in dummy v
out verts v
"""

self.inputs[0].hide_safe = True

verts.append([])
verts[0].extend([[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [2,0,0]])
```

In the above example, the `self` represents the class instance of that node.